# How can i handle a local notification when the app is in the background and execute a function?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3, notifications

How can i handle a local notification to wake an app from the background to execute a needed function without the user intervention (i.e. pressing a notification banner)? Is there any ways to do that? I need to execute a function which turns MPPlayer on in a specific time after receiving a notification.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. The two closest solutions I can think of are 1) silent *remote* notifications managed from your server, or 2) background update mode - the timing of which you have no control over.